# How to update encryption type of the kerberos stash?

Tags: kerberos

Recent security updates have started causing the following warning to appear in `kdc` logs:

```
krb5kdc[1127011]: Stash file /etc/krb5kdc/stash uses DEPRECATED enctype des3-cbc-sha1
```

Given that newer versions of openSSL will stop supporting various ciphers altogether, I want to change this file to a non-deprecated type before my kerberos system breaks.

- How do I change the encryption type of a stash file?
- What do I change in the configuration to continue being able to read the stash file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's MIT Kerberos itself that plans to drop support for 3DES long before OpenSSL does. (OpenSSL isn't likely to drop 3DES support fully; in version 3.0 it was simply moved to the 'legacy' provider.)

A stash file is not encrypted in itself – it holds an encryption *key* that allows the rest of your Kerberos database to be read. Updating it therefore means re-encrypting all principal keys with a new master key, then storing that key in the stash file again.

So you're looking for the MIT Kerberos "master key rotation" procedure which is documented in:

- https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/database.html#updating-master-key

In short, use `kdb5_util` to add and "use" a new mkey, then to re-encrypt existing data with it, generate a new stash, and finally purge the old mkey.

(Just to clarify, the master key is *not* the krbtgt key, although that may also need rotation if your realm is that old. I have a [script](https://github.com/grawity/code/blob/main/kerberos/krb5-find-legacy-keys.py) for checking which principals are missing keys for modern enctypes.)

You might also find the "Retiring DES" document useful; it was about single-DES retirement but most procedures apply in general to the removal of any enctype:

- https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/advanced/retiring-des.html